# How to parse postgresql binary timestamp?

Tags: c, postgresql, binary, timestamp

I a ma trying to parse a postgresql timestamp value returned by PQGetValue in binary format.  . I am trying to convert it to a struct tm with this function :

```
#define PG_EPOCH_TIME_T   946681200 // pg epoch in unix epoch
static inline int _convert_pg_timestamp_to_tm( struct tm* _tm, uint64_t pg_timestamp )
{
    int64_t i;
    struct tm tm;
    struct tm* p;
    uint64_t u;

    u = be64toh(pg_timestamp);
    memcpy( &i, &u, sizeof(uint64_t) );

    i /= 1000000;
    i += PG_EPOCH_TIME_T;


//    p = gmtime_r( &i, &tm );
    p = localtime_r( &i, &tm );
    if( p != &tm )
        return -1;
    dump_tm( &tm );

    memset( _tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm) );

    _tm->tm_year = tm.tm_year;
    _tm->tm_mon = tm.tm_mon;
    _tm->tm_mday = tm.tm_mday;

    _tm->tm_hour = tm.tm_hour;
    _tm->tm_min = tm.tm_min;
    _tm->tm_sec = tm.tm_sec;

    dump_tm( _tm );

    return 0;
}
```

AD datetime seems to work correctly but if i try  the minimal value that this type can hold ( 4713-01-01 00:00:00 BC ), i have incorrect value :
*Wed Dec 31 23:09:21 -4713*

I don't think this 8 bytes value is just the number of microseconds relative to pg epoch. There's maybe some bits or a byte dedicated to other purpose. Also there's another timestamp type with timezone information who had the same range value and the timezone information with the same data length, so there is the some space reserverd to it and so the data is not only a delta.

Despite my searchs, i haven't found any documentation that expose the structure of it. That why i asked this question : Can someone tell me what is the underlined stucture of this 8 bytes length data ?

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: You seem to asking about the behavior for incorrect dates.  Does the code work for correct dates, like in 2023?

Comment: yes all AD datetime i have tested works even the maximal value which is 294276-12-31 23:59:59 (without microseconds ) work.

Comment: So does it work for dates in the year 1965? 1945? 1935?

Comment: yes it work for all > 0000

Comment: *Another timestamp type with timezone information*, this is **not correct**, Postgres does not store the timezone nor the offset. The data type you refer to is `timestamp with time zone` or `timestamptz`. Postgres converts the value to UTC based on server's timezone setting when stored. Then converts to the current time based on the timezone setting.  So there is nothing in the stored structure indicating timezone, it is the type definition doing so.

Comment: Yes your are right, pg server return only a int64 which is and only a delta. i have digged a lot and finaly go to the conclusion that i cannot rely on time_t based functions to compute time before unix epoch.

Comment: @mystackoverflowpseudo In my experience, the Unix `time_t` functions work well across all values.  There's generally no problem with negative values which end up being before 1970.  If `time_t` is limited to 32 bits you obviously can't go much before 1902, but for a 64-bit `time_t` there's really no limit — you run out of bits for `tm_year` before you run out of bits in your `time_t` value.  But then there are lots of *other* ambiguities when you try to work with dates and times far in the past, like Julian versus Gregorian calendars, and whether there was a year 0.